# passport.js how to make Multiple req.user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

In my app there are two types of users (seller and buyer) Authentication works fine but I am not able to create seperate req.user so that i can use them in my ejs files, I am new to coding thankyou for helping me out.

both users are diffrent in database but for session they are the same user.

**app.js**

```
passport.use('userLocal', new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.use('sellerLocal', new LocalStrategy(Seller.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    if (user!=null)
        done(null, user);
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {                           
    res.locals.currentUser=req.user;      
    res.locals.success=req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error=req.flash('error');
    next();
})
```

**Seller.js**

```
route.post('/register/seller', catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { proprietorname, companyname, address, contactnumber, email, username, password }=req.body;
        const seller=new Seller({ proprietorname, companyname, address, contactnumber, email, username });
        const registeredSeller=await Seller.register(seller, password);
        req.login(registeredSeller, err => {                              //after registering it logins the registered user
            if (err) return next(err);
            req.flash('success', 'SELLER LOGIN');
            res.redirect('/products');
        })
    } catch (e) {
        req.flash('error', e.message);
        res.redirect('/register/seller')
    }

}));


route.get('/login/seller', (req, res) => {
    res.render('users/sellerLogin')

})
route.post('/login/seller', passport.authenticate('sellerLocal', { failureFlash: true, failureRedirect: '/login/seller', keepSessionInfo: true, }), (req, res) => { //a authentication middleware by passport you can add google fb twiiter too insted of just local
    req.flash('success', 'yooooo');
    const redirectUrl=req.session.returnTo||"/products";
    delete req.session.returnTo;
    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
});
```

**user.js**

```
route.post('/register/buyer', catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    // res.send(req.body);
    try {
        const { email, username, password }=req.body;
        const user=new User({ email, username });
        const registeredUser=await User.register(user, password);       //registering user
        req.login(registeredUser, err => {                              //after registering it logins the registered user
            if (err) return next(err);
            req.flash('success', 'Welcome to SnapBuy');
            res.redirect('/products');
        })
    } catch (e) {
        req.flash('error', e.message);
        res.redirect('/register/buyer')
    }
}));


route.get('/login/buyer', (req, res) => {
    res.render('users/buyerLogin')

})

route.post('/login/buyer', passport.authenticate('userLocal', { failureFlash: true, failureRedirect: '/login/buyer', keepSessionInfo: true, }), (req, res) => { //a authentication middleware by passport you can add google fb twiiter too insted of just local
    req.flash('success', 'Welcome Back');
    const redirectUrl=req.session.returnTo||"/products";
    delete req.session.returnTo;
    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
});

route.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
    req.logout();
    req.flash('success', "Goodbye!");
    res.redirect('/products');
});
```

Comment: Do the simple thing and set a type for them, or flag, like `req.user.isSeller`.

Comment: @caTS can you show me how? I am trying but it is giving me undefined.